# How can I set a different screen timeout time when on battery than if I am plugged in?

Tags: 14.04, power-management, battery, lock-screen, timeout

Currently, Ubuntu 14.04 only provides a single option: "Turn screen off when inactive for: x minutes" that applies regardless of whether my laptop is plugged in or not.  I want to change this setting when on battery power, just like I can with other Power options such as the suspend timeout.  Is there any built-in way to do this?  If not, I think I should be able to write a script that gets called by `dbus` whenever the power state changes, and modifies the gsettings key org.gnome.desktop.session.idle-delay.

This is basically a dupe of questions:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/435783 and 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/483356.

Still hoping for an elegant solution.

Comment: You can [vote for this basic feature](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity-control-center/+bug/1723798) and hope for the best, or you can use [Linux Mint, which has let you set different screen lock times for AC Power vs. Battery](https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=149531) since at least 2013.