# How can I change sleep timeout when on AC on Ubuntu MATE?

Tags: 18.04, suspend, ubuntu-mate, dconf

I used dconf editor to change my sleep timeout to 300 seconds when on AC, but the change doesn't seem to be effective.

I'm using ubuntu MATE 18.04

Is the sleep timeout not configurable?

[image: dconf editor screenshot]

Comment: What Ubuntu version and interface are you using?

Comment: Edited question. What do you mean by interface?

Comment: Please add to your question what the value's name is in the dconf editor and what you changed it to.

Comment: Sorry interface is an old phrase for desktop manager. In your case it is Mate but for regular Ubuntu they can choose between Gnome and Unity which have different power management screens.

Comment: @fixit7 what is the output of `sudo gsettings get org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power sleep-inactive-ac-type` i think by default it is something like "nothing" to make this value to "sleep" `sudo gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power sleep-inactive-ac-type blank`

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/a/1075209/739431

Comment: suspend is the output of the gsettings command.

Comment: @fixit7 that's fine about first command. it means after 300 seconds of in activity it will suspend. Have you tried the second command in my comment?

Comment: Second command resulted in no change.