# How do I get the screen to lgo blank in Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: display, lock-screen

I have a desktop running Ubuntu 18.04 with Gnome, and two monitors. The screen does not automatically go blank or lock itself. I can manually lock the screen, but if I, say, go to bed, when I wake up in the morning the screen is still as I left it. Through Settings-> Power -> Power Saving, I have 'Blank Screen' set at 10 minutes, but that doesn't happen.

I'm not sure where to start trying to investigate what is going wrong. How do I get my screen to  go blank? I don't really care whether it locks or not, I just do want it to turn off my monitors.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/a/1075209/739431 can you try this by setting time to 1minute for testing.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @PRATAP for pointing me in the right direction.

Install `dconf-editor` using

```
user@server:~$ sudo apt install dconf-editor
```

Go to `/org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/power/sleep-inactive-ac-timeout`; set "Custom value" to desired time until timeout (I chose 10 minutes, or 600 seconds)

Go to `/org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/power/sleep-inactive-ac-type`; set "Custom value" to the type of action to take. I chose 'blank' to go to blank screen but other options include logout, hibernate, suspend, etc.