# timout settings blank screen don't work

Tags: 18.04, screen, lock-screen, ubuntu-mate, timeout

I have since installing 18.04 not been able to get the system to obey my selected timout for blank screen. I set "never" but after 10 minutes inactivity the screen goes blank whatever settings I have chosen. It's really enoyung vwhilst I'm watching a movie or such. Even using VLC it goes blank. Only SMPlayer overrides whichever devilish settings is activated without my knowledge. Been searching the net for answers but find nothing to solve this problem. Please help!
Using 18.04 Mate on a desktop computer.

Comment: the connected screen is a TV or monitor?

Comment: I have both connected but there is no difference as the problem is the system. What makes it blank the screens when I've set it to "never"?

Comment: i have a system which is set to never blank in all aspects.. but my TV setting has no setting to stop going sleep maximum of 30mins..so even my system knows it should not be blank.. when i watch a movie.. after 30min i need a mouse movment or any activity to wake the TV and in this case Ubuntuis not responsible in my case..

Comment: when i connect same pc to a HP monitor.. it didn't happen.. even for 6hrs..the system just shows where i left it.. (lot of power wasted rite? )

Comment: can you have a look on this.. https://askubuntu.com/a/1075209/739431

Comment: I followed the link above and uset dconf-editor to change settings for activitys "sleep" and screen timout in both Gnome and Mate settings. Nothing changed! This is so frustrating, never had this problem before as normal settings in Preferences should work fine.