# There is no "Suspend & Power Button" option in Settings > Power menu

Tags: 18.04, suspend, power-management

All...

My question is about power management feature.

I've arleady searched a lot of articles, but I couldn't find the solution of my case. I'd like to get the exact solution.

As the title, on my Settings > Power menu, there is no "Suspend & Power Button" option. So, I can't adjust the time of suspend/hibernate. Is there any answer of why? and how to solve this sistuation?

[image: This is my captured image of Setting > Power menu]

[image: This is my captured image of Ubuntu version]

Comment: Have you chkd `privacy` tab?

Comment: Excuse me, as your mention, where/what is the privacy tab? I've not checked privacy tab.

Comment: After commenting, I've checked privacy tab in Settings. But, there is no related options of suspend/hibernate.

Comment: 0k can you install `gnome-tweaks` with the command `sudo apt install gnome-tweaks`

Comment: I've already installed gnome-tweaks and checked. On the Power tab of GNOME Tweaks, there is only one option of "Suspend when laptop lid is closed [ON/OFF]". As reference, my computer is desktop environment, not laptop.

Comment: 0k..clear..install `dconf-editor`

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/q/1075188/739431

Comment: Ok, I will try to use dconf-editor and provide the result. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I have the same issue running:
Ubuntu 20.10
64-bit
GNOME 3.38.1

Nothing shows up under Settings>Power>Suspend & Power Button

I used this to disable sleep

```
sudo systemctl mask sleep.target suspend.target hibernate.target hybrid-sleep.target
```

and this to enable it again

```
sudo systemctl unmask sleep.target suspend.target hibernate.target hybrid-sleep.target
```

Comment: this worked for me!