# Screen does not blanks after timeout

Tags: power-management

After upgrading to 20.04, my screen does not blanks after the given timeout. 
When I performed the upgrade, I got a notification of the upgrader that screen blanking would be disabled. 
After the upgrade, I think i set everything to enable it again, but it does not work apparently.
Here are 2 screenshots of my settings:
[image]
[image]

Did I overlook some setting?

[Edit]
Output of `gsettings list-recursively | grep idle-delay`

```
org.cinnamon.desktop.session idle-delay uint32 900
org.gnome.desktop.session idle-delay uint32 60

(process:26641): GLib-GIO-WARNING **: 19:12:59.864: Failed to parse translated string '['attachment',‘bijlage’,'attaching','attached',‘bijgevoegd’,'enclosed',‘ingesloten’]' for key 'attachment-reminder-clues' in schema 'org.gnome.evolution.plugin.attachment-reminder': 14:expected value

(process:26641): GLib-GIO-WARNING **: 19:12:59.864: Using untranslated default instead.
```

[edit 2]
Output for command `echo $XDG_SESSION_DESKTOP`

```
ubuntu
```

Output for `dpkg -l | grep cinnamon`

```
ii  cinnamon-desktop-data                                       4.4.1-3                                       all          Common files for Cinnamon desktop apps
ii  cinnamon-l10n                                               4.4.2-2                                       all          Translation files for the Cinnamon desktop
ii  cinnamon-session                                            4.4.1-1                                       amd64        Cinnamon Session Manager - Minimal runtime
ii  cinnamon-session-common                                     4.4.1-1                                       all          Cinnamon Session Manager - common files
ii  libcinnamon-desktop4:amd64                                  4.4.1-3                                       amd64        Cinnamon library for loading .desktop files
```

[edit 3]
output for `gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.lockdown disable-lock-screen`

```
false
```

Comment: @PRATAP: I've updated my post with the output of your command.

Comment: @PRATAP ok see my original post for update. I cannot remember I've installed cinnamon or such. Last year I did have problems getting into gnome tough, cannot remember what I did to fix this tough.

Comment: output is `false`

Comment: Ok.. is it a laptop?

Comment: Indeed. In fact, the laptop is like 12-13 years old. Maybe I just give it a fresh install of 20.04 as I've had several occasions where I almost bricked it. A clean install could maybe freshen things up.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/q/1075188/739431

Comment: @PRATAP It worked! It turned out the value for 'sleep-inactive-ac-type' & `sleep-inactive-battery-type` was `nothing`for both. I changed it to `blank` and now my screen does blank out after the given timeout. Thanks a lot!